# How to add a afade effect to a complex filter (In this case volume)?

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is my current command :

```
ffmpeg -i [videoFilepath] -i [musicFile] -stream_loop -1 -shortest -filter_complex "[1]volume=0.15:enable=between(t\,4\,10)+between(t\,14\,20)[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2" -map 0:v:0 [outputFilepath]
```

What it does :

- Takes a video file as an input
- Takes a music file as an input
- Loops the music if it is shorter than the video duration
- If the music is longer, outputs a file the duration of the video
- Reduce volume by 85% between 4 and 10 seconds as well as between 14 and 20 seconds
- Mixes the 2 audio streams so we have both the original video audio non-filtered and the music with the volume filter
- Outputs a video file

I want the volume filter to ease-in and ease-out for a duration of 1 second, instead of abruptly changing. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick, maybe imperfect solution – use an expression in the `volume` filter, e.g. for linearly decreasing volume from 1 to 0.15 in the time interval between 4<sup>th</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> second:

```
volume=1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4):eval=frame
```

For time  t=4, the volume will evaluate to 1, for t=5 it will be 0.15:

```
for t=4:    1 - 0.85 / (5-4) * (4-4) = 1 - 0.85 / (10-4) * 0 = 1 - 0 = 1
for t=5:    1 - 0.85 / (5-4) * (5-4) = 1 - 0.85 = 0.15
```

[image]

---

You may use (nested) `if` functions for evaluating the volume value in different time intervals of your audio stream.

For example, to keep the value 1 for the first 4 seconds you may extend the previous formula

```
              1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4)
```

with the help of the `lt` (less than) function into

```
if(lt(t\,4),1,1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4))
```

[image]

and then – for keeping the value 0.15 after 5<sup>th</sup> second – into

```
if(lt(t\,4),1,if(lt(t\,5),1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4),0.15))
```

[image]

And so on, always rewriting the last item with a new `if` function.

Of course, the resulting expression is not the optimal one, but the procedure is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer @MarianD.
From your question i came up with this function to decrease the volume : `1 - [ (1 - percentage) / ( stop - start) ] * ( time - start)`

And this is for the linearly increasing the volume : `1 - [ (1 - percentage) / (stop - start) ] * (stop - time)`

My question is now : I want the volume to decrease to 15% over 1s then stay at the same level between 2 times and finally increase back up to 100% over 1s. How would i go about doing that ?

Comment: @Nobunaji, I extended my answer to show you how to progressively build the expression for your particular need.

Comment: finally: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=sin(440*2*PI*t)" -af "
volume='if(lt(t,4)+between(t,10,14)+gt(t,20),1,
if(between(t,4,5),1-0.85*(t-4),
if(between(t,9,10),0.15+0.85*(t-9),
if(between(t,14,15),1-0.85*(t-14),
if(between(t,19,20),0.15+0.85*(t-19),
0.15)))))':eval=frame
" -b:a 320k -t 23 -y /tmp/out.mp3`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов, nice, you are a smart man – why not to put it as another answer and gain some reputation points?

Comment: @MarianD Why in your expression you put `if(lt(t\,4),1,if(lt(t\,5),1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4),0.15))` and not `if(lt(t, 4), 1), if(lt(t, 5), 1-0.85/(5-4)*(t-4),0.15))` ? This makes more sense to me than to have one if inside of another.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Can any of you two tell me what is wrong with the edited section of my original question ?

Comment: Nobunaji, **1.** Yes, your expression seems better than mine. — **2.** Please consider accepting my answer, if it is useful for you (click on the check mark near its start). — **3.** Your edited part is another question, please let us at first finish the original one. Put the edited part in the form of another, new question, please.

Comment: It's done @MarianD. Here is a link to the new question : https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36556/error-initializing-complex-filters-using-volume-filter-in-fluent-ffmpeg